# Unable to retrieve more than 10k records from Google Analytics

Tags: c#, google-analytics-api

I've developed a windows console application which extracts Google Analytics data and writes to .CSV file. When queried for data of particular date on Google Analytics Query Explorer, it displayed:- "Your query matched 96782 results...".

The problem is when when i query for the data of same date using application, by default it returns only 1000 records and when I set

`DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest objRequest.MaxResult` more than 10k, then it gives me max to max 10k records.

Is there any way to get records more than 10k.

Comment: The limit of 10K records can be found on various places on the web. When you run into this limit, perhaps it's useful to contact Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what i did is, I set Request.MaxResult = 10000 and Response.ItemsPerPage = 10000. The vital role is played by Request.StartIndex which has pagination mechanism e.g. in 1st loop we'll get 1-10000 rows then 10001-20000....20001-30000 and so on.

Under loop, request to data of a particular day initially is set to Request.StartIndex = 1 and then consecutively increases to MaxResult + 1 as soon as row count reaches 10000th row e.g.:-
Request.StartIndex = 1 then 10001 then 20001....30001...40001 and so on untill Response.Rows == null.

Here's my code:-

```
            StringBuilder sbrCSVData = new StringBuilder();
            int intStartIndex = 1;
            int intIndexCnt = 0;
            int intMaxRecords = 10000;

            AnalyticsService objAnaSrv = new AnalyticsService(objInit);
            string metrics = "ga:visitors,ga:visits,ga:visitBounceRate,ga:pageviews,ga:pageviewsPerVisit,ga:uniquePageviews,ga:avgTimeOnPage,ga:exits,ga:avgPageLoadTime,ga:goal1ConversionRate";
            DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest objRequest = objAnaSrv.Data.Ga.Get(strProfId, startDate,endDate, metrics);
            objRequest.Dimensions = "ga:visitCount,ga:browser,ga:browserVersion,ga:IsMobile,ga:screenResolution,ga:date,ga:hour";
            objRequest.MaxResults = 10000;

            while (true)
            {
                objRequest.StartIndex = intStartIndex;
                GaData objResponse = objRequest.Fetch();
                objResponse.ItemsPerPage = intMaxRecords;

                  if (objResponse.Rows != null)
                {
                    intIndexCnt++;
                    for (int intRows = 0; intRows < objResponse.Rows.Count; intRows++)
                    {
                        IList<string> lstRow = objResponse.Rows[intRows];
                        for (int intCols = 0; intCols <= lstRow.Count - 1; intCols++)
                        {
                            strRowData += lstRow[intCols].ToString() + "|";
                        }
                        strRowData = strRowData.Remove(strRowData.Length - 1, 1);
                        sbrCSVData.Append(strRowData + "\r\n");
                        strRowData = "";
                    }
                    intStartIndex = intIndexCnt * intMaxRecords + 1;
                }
                else break;
            }
```

Comment: Nice Implementation Pratik

Answer (score 0):

Yes this thing is mentioned in there documentation.
To get more data, general practice is break it down your interval or any criteria then do multiple queries to fetch the data.
Read https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/limits-quotas for full detail
Hope it might help you a bit