# Google Analytics API V3 Access with C#

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api

So I am trying to create an application that periodically pulls data from GA.  I have found numerous threads on this topic and none seem to quite work correctly.  In addition the documentation provided by Google pretty much sucks (for lack of a better term).  Was wondering if anyone has been able to accomplish this, and can provide a true end-to-end description/walk through.

Thanks,

Barak

Comment: Can you show which of the numerous threads you read came closest to answering the question, show what code you tried based on that, and it will make it easier for people to fill in the gaps so that you move from there to a working solution to your problem.

Comment: Barak Poker I don't know how we can contact indivisual on stackoverflow. Please connect me via my linked profile. I will further guide u in it's usage. it's difficult but really awesome set of apis

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you go with the V3 API Nuget:

```
pm> Install-Package Google.Apis.Analytics.v3 -Pre
```

Start by looking into and understanding how the OAUTH2 login works:  [Google OAuth2 C#](http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-csharp/)
Then you can look into how to make requests though to Analytics. [Google Analytic’s API v3 with C#](http://www.daimto.com/google-analytics-api-v3-with-c/)

This question is really open.  This site really isn't for requesting links.  If you have tried other tutorials post what you have tried, and what's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I agreed about lack of documentation specially for .net.I were able to fetch data by converting some java code to C# equivalnet code as i have some experience in java as well .
Check this link [Unable to retrieve more than 10k records from Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829512/unable-to-retreive-more-than-10k-records-from-google-analytics/16832878#16832878)

and also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-analytics-data-export-api/maa_fyjD2cM/2ZxM52BinmUJ

which might help u.